# Foreign-key automatically fill in the form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-haystack

I have four models of the shop, customer, product, an order.
I am showing the relation of models

### shop

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='shop', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### customer

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

### product

```
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

### order

```
shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.CASCADE, null=True)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

when customers login then the shop will print on the screen and a button on shop to show the products by the shop in the form card

how I can create an order form so that the customer in order is the instance and the shop in order is that shop which is selected to show the products and  every  card of the product have a field to fill the remaining detail and submit

Comment: How did you go?

Comment: I am confused to do this you can recommend to me an idea. if make I make add button on the products card and after submit the list of the added product will  print with the field of remaining information like the quantity  etc to fill them

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would add it to the form, with one of the following two options
Option 1

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Get the shop_id from the URL
    shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, pk=shop_id)
    # Create a form and add it the context
    form = OrderForm(
        # This is where the magic happens
        initial={"shop": shop], "customer": self.request.user})
    # Use this if you want to hide it as well
    form.fields['item'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Option 2

```
# If the form is already created you can use this pattern
context['form'].fields['shop'].initial = shop
context['form'].fields['customer'].initial = self.request.user
```